# Ember.RSVP.All error Array Methods must be provided an Array

Tags: ember.js, rsvp.js, rsvp-promise

[Cross-posted from discuss.emberjs.com](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-rsvp-all-error-array-methods-must-be-provided-an-array/6563)

I'm trying to save a model then upon successful save save some additional models related to the intial model. These are in standard input fields that I can't/don't know how to bind to ED so I'm just using standard jQuery selectors to find the inputs and save the models. All models are saving properly but `Ember.RSVP.all` is hitting the `REJECT` callback due to an `Array Methods must be provided an Array` error. I'm not sure exactly where I'm supposed to be providing an array...

I've inspected various elements along the way and `var promises` is an array of promises as expected. The only thing I can think of is the `results` value being passed into my resolve callback is supposed to be an array? If that's the case I'm not sure how to make it an array other than maybe just passing in `Ember.A()` or `[]`

Here is the relevant code in my controller.

```
submit: function () {
    var self = this;
    var division = this.get('model');
    var isNew = division.get('isNew');

    if(isNew) {
        division.setProperties({
            vendor: self.get('parentVendor'),
            vendorCategory: self.get('selectedCategory'),
            isActive: true,
            createdBy: 1,
            createdDate: moment().format()
        });
    } else {
        division.setProperties({
            vendorCategory: self.get('selectedCategory'),
            modifiedBy: 1,
            modifiedDate: moment().format()
        });
    }

    division.validate().then(function () {
        if (division.get('isValid')) {
            division.save().then(function(result) {

                /*
                    this bit of hackishness loops through each of the attribute input fields, creates a new DS.model for that attribute, 
                    saves the model, then returns the resulting promise to the promises array so they can be processed by RSVP.all to 
                    ensure that all the attributes save properly.
                 */

                // map the promises array
                var promises = $('input.attribute').map(function () {
                    var elem = $(this)[0];
                    var vendorTypeAttrId = $(elem).attr('data-attribute-id'),
                        attrValue = $(elem).val();

                    // create the model
                    var model = self.store.createRecord('vendor-division-attribute', {
                        division: result,
                        vendorTypeAttribute: self.get('categoryAttributes').findBy('id', vendorTypeAttrId),
                        value: attrValue,
                        createdBy: 1,
                        createdDate: moment().format()
                    });

                    // return the save promise
                    var p = model.save();
                    return p;
                });

                // Make sure all promises are resolved before continuing
                Ember.RSVP.all(promises).then(function (results) {
                    // it worked! keep calm and move along
                    self.send('closeModal');
                    var msg = isNew ? division.get('name') + ' Created!' : 'Changes saved!';
                    Bootstrap.NM.push(msg, 'success');
                }).catch(function(reason) {
                    // something went wrong - display the error
                    if (typeof reason.error !== 'undefined') {
                        // DSP error
                        if (Ember.keys(reason.error).length > 0) {
                            error = reason.error[0].message;
                        } else {
                            error = 'An error occured while saving your changes';
                        }
                    } else if (typeof reason.message !== 'undefined') {
                        error = reason.message;
                    } else {
                        error = reason;
                    }
                    console.log(error);
                    Bootstrap.NM.push('Error saving Vendor Division: ' + error, 'danger');
                });

            }, function(reason) {
                var error;
                if (typeof reason.error !== 'undefined') {
                    // DSP error
                    if (Ember.keys(reason.error).length > 0) {
                        error = reason.error[0].message;
                    } else {
                        error = 'An error occured while saving your changes';
                    }
                } else if (typeof reason.message !== 'undefined') {
                    error = reason.message;
                } else {
                    error = reason;
                }
                console.log(error);
                Bootstrap.NM.push('Error saving Vendor Division: ' + error, 'danger');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `promises` array isn't really an array. jQuery returns an array-like object, not a true array. Try running this code in your console and you'll see:

```
var a = $('a').map(function() { return 1; });
console.log(Array.isArray(a));
console.log(a instanceof Array);
```

Luckily, jQuery provides a nice `makeArray` function to solve this problem. After you declare `promises`, but before you call `Ember.RSVP.all`, insert this line:

```
promises = $.makeArray(promises);
```

Comment: So the issue was actually with `$('input.attribute').map(function () { ... }`? After reading the [$.map docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) it seems that way. Thanks for the clarification!